# variable changed before modifiying it in js async function

Tags: javascript

```
...
  const a = {
    data: { records: [1, 2, 3] },
  };

  const asyncfunction = (prop) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(prop);
      }, 500);
    });
  };
  const fetch = async () => {
    const res1 = await asyncfunction(a);
    console.log(res1); //output 1,2,3,11111
    a.data.records.push(11111);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);
```

I created a test component to demonstrate this. I thought the console.log will catch the result of await expression immediately and output 1,2,3. How come it becomes 1,2,3,11111 even before I modified it?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: cause it is how javascript work. event loop

Comment: @elpmid Uhm, no, this is not how Javascript works…

Comment: or the nature? of how event loops works?

Comment: every async process is send on the javascript runtime before sent to the event looop?

Comment: @elpmid No idea what you're talking about… The array does not contain values which are pushed into it on the following line. Javascript isn't *that* async.

Comment: then i dont have idea what you talking about too